# cannot pass variable through callback nor can I put promise on function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

So I have a data set hard coded that I need to loop through to check the distance from the user entered distance using googles web api for checking this works I just can't pass an id variable down through my code to where I need to be able to access it so that I can print depending on the answer I get from the api.

my code is like this:

```
checkDist(data) {
  this.setState({
    searching: true,
  });
  var self = this;
  data.forEach(item => {
    console.log('check');
    self.getDist(item.postcode, item.id);
  });
}

updateSearchResults(dist) {
  var output = [];
  var self = this;
  console.log('Here we will search the db using user data for suitable jobs');
  console.log("distFromLoc in Update: " + this.state.distFromLoc);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    self.setState({
      dataToShow: output,
      searching: false,
      current: 1,
    });
    const dataLength = self.state.dataToShow.length
    self.setState({
      amountOfJobs: dataLength
    })}, 10000)
  }
getDist(dest, id){
  var self = this;
  const wrappedCallback = (id) => (...args) => this.callback(...args);
  var origin = this.state.location,
    destination = dest,
    service = new window.google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false,
      unitSystem: window.google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
    }, 
    wrappedCallback,
  );
}

callback(response, status, id) {
  const self = this;
  console.log("id in callback: " + id);
  if(status === "OK") {
    console.log(response);
    var dest = response.destinationAddresses[0];
    if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS"){

      } else if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "OK"){
        var dist = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
        this.setState({
          distFromLoc: dist
        }, function() {
          self.updateSearchResults(dist);
        })
      }
    } else {
      alert("Error: " + status);
    }
  }
```

the ID gets passed through to the final function by changing `const wrappedCallback = (...args) => this.callback(...args);` to `const wrappedCallback = (id) => (...args) => this.callback(...args);` but this breaks the final function as it doesn't console log the response or the status anymore that it did when the const was the first way but the first way doesn't know what the id is.

Is there a way that I can make it know what the id, response, and status all mean as they are all required for stuff.

Comment: you could change your callback passing from `wrappedCallback` to a inline fatarrow like `(response, status) => callback(response, status, id)` you pass it a callback that accepts its arguments then calls your function with the extra argument.

Comment: ill try that thanks. so i need to change where i call wrappedCallback and add this in instead??

Comment: I added an answer with a fuller explanation.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing extra variables into another function can be done by a fairly simple pattern.

Say you have a function that says hi to a name

```
const hi = (name) => console.log(`hi ${name}`);
```

And you want to pass this function to a setTimeout which accepts a function

```
setTimeout(hi, 1000);
```

Well obviously cannot pass in the name now as is the case for your `id`, but if we wrap that function we can pass more arguments by passing an anonymous function.

```
setTimeout(() => hi('bill'), 1000);
```

in the same way you can wrap your call to callback such as

```
(response, status) => callback(response, status, id)
```

as long as id is in scope during this declaration.
The full function change would be:

```
getDist(dest, id){
  var self = this;
  var origin = this.state.location,
    destination = dest,
    service = new window.google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false,
      unitSystem: window.google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
    }, 
    (response, status) => callback(response, status, id),
  );
}
```